# How to Categorize virtual pageviews in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events

I checked in [google analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) that in tracking events :

`_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`
we can categorize the events.
I am using pop-ups for login/register and i am handling these in analytics by using concept of *virtual pageviews*.
My question is, Is there any way to categorize virtual pageviews (like for register and login separately), i couldn't found any solution because for pageviews we have `_trackPageview('url')`
and here we have no parameter for setting up the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. You could add an event with your virtual page view and log them both at the same time.
2. You could add a prefix to the virtual page view such as `"/virtual/" + url`

Answer (score 1):

There are no categories for PageViews in Google Analytics, but there are reports that really help you segment this data.  For example, you can easily search for specific content or build Advanced Segments that show you users that have visited a specific page during their session.

**Events**: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#Categories

> For Event Tracking, a category is a name that you supply as a way to
>   group objects that you want to track. It is the first parameter used
>   in the _trackEvent() method and it is required.

**Pageviews**: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57164

> A pageview is defined as a view of a page on your site that is being
>   tracked by the Analytics tracking code. If a visitor hits reload after
>   reaching the page, this will be counted as an additional pageview. If
>   a user navigates to a different page and then returns to the original
>   page, a second pageview will be recorded as well.